# GCP: How to access a L2 VM (qemu) running in a pod in gcp by IP from internet?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

i have a cluster of 2 nodes created in gcp. the worker node (L1 VM) has nested virtualization enabled. i have created a pod in this L1 VM. and i have launched a L2 VM using qemu in this pod.
my objective is to access this L2 VM only by a IP address from external word (internet). there are many services running in my VM (L2 VM) and i need to access it only by IP.

i created a tunnel from node to L2 VM (which is within pod) to get dhcp address to my VM. but it seems dhcp offer and ack messages are blocked by google cloud.

i have got a public IP in the cluster through which i can reach to private IP of node. most probably there is a NAT configured in the cloud for the node's private IP.
can i configure node as a NAT gw so that i can push this packet further from internet to L2 VM?

any other suggestions are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to implement something like a [bastion host](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bastion_host). However, this is something that you shouldn't do with kubernetes. Although you 'can' implement it with kubernetes, it is simply not made for it.

I see there two vivid options for you:

A. Create another virtual machine (GCE instance) inside the same VPC as the cluster and set it up as a bastion host or as an endpoint for a VPN.

B. You can use the identity aware proxy (IAP) to tunnel the traffic to your machine inside the VPC as described [here](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/enabling-kubernetes-howto)

The IAP is probably the best solution for your usecase.

Also consider using simple GCE instances as opposed to a kubernetes cluster. A kubernetes cluster is very useful if you have a lot of workload that is too much for one node or if you need to scale out and in etc. Your usecase looks to me more that you still think in the traditional server world and less about [cattle vs pets](https://iamondemand.com/blog/devops-concepts-pets-vs-cattle/).

Comment: I have got following link from google         
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/nested-virtualization/creating-nested-vms#creating_an_l2_vm_with_network_access_from_outside_the_l1_vm

It has described how to access L2 VM from outside L1 VM. I have tried this and it works. even it works if I try to connect L2 VM from internet. But there is a problem while trying to connect from internet. Google claims it as “man in the middle” attack. They say it correctly because I nat-ed the primary internal IP of L1 VM to L2 VM IP.

Comment: My objective is to nat the alias-IP of L1 VM primary interface to L2 VM. But problem is that all the request from internet was coming to primary IP of L1 VM. So nat-ing of alias-Ip is not helping. According to google doc, this is also correct because if a network interface has both public and private IPv4 address then vpc does one-one nat with primary IP address of the interface, not with the alias-IP. Hence requests are coming to primary IP address.

Comment: If I can update nat table or other configuration to update the incoming request to alias-IP (not the primary IP) then this man in the middle attack will disappear.